# Infinitely looping background as character moves in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a background image and a separate ground image that I want to loop infinitely as long as the character is moving forward. When the character stops, the background and ground should not be moving. For similar games it is often suggested to add `this.game.background.tilePosition.x -= 1` 
to the update function. This is not what I am looking for as it makes the background constantly move regardless of whether the character is moving. At the moment my background and ground images are repeating, but they are restricted to `this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 800);`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
function Hero(game, x, y) {
        Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'player');
//rest of code for Hero constructor....
}

Hero.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Hero.prototype.constructor = Hero;

//code for Hero.prototype....

PlayState = {};

PlayState.init = function () {
   //code for keyboard...
};

PlayState.preload = function () {

      this.game.load.json('level:1', 'data/level01.json');

      this.game.load.image('ground', 'images/ground.png'); // I need this to 
      //repeat infinitely

      this.game.load.image('background', 'images/background.png'); // I need 
      //this to repeat infinitely

      this.game.load.spritesheet('player', 'images/player.png', 64, 64);

};


PlayState.create = function () {

      this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 800);

      this.game.background = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 
      this.game.world.width, 800, 'background');

      this.game.ground = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 680, 
      this.game.world.width, 166, 'ground');

      this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.game.ground);
      this.game.ground.body.immovable = true;
      this.game.ground.body.allowGravity = false; 

      this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

      this._loadLevel(this.game.cache.getJSON('level:1'));

};


PlayState.update = function () {

      this.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.game.ground); 

 };

PlayState._loadLevel = function (data) {

       this._spawnPlayer({player: data.player});
       const GRAVITY = 1200;
       this.game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = GRAVITY;
      };

PlayState._spawnPlayer = function (data) {

       this.player = new Hero(this.game, data.player.x, data.player.y);
       this.game.add.existing(this.player);
       this.game.camera.follow(this.player, 
        Phaser.Camera.FOLLOW_PLATFORMER);
      };

window.onload = function () {
        let game = new Phaser.Game(866, 520, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');
        game.state.add('play', PlayState);
        game.state.start('play');
};
```

I have tried the following solution (see below) where I create a constructor function for the background. This idea is from an existing tutorial done in TypeScript that does exactly what I am looking for. However, I am not familiar with TypeScript so I have just tried to interpret the code from the tutorial as best I can and put it into Javascript but at the moment I am getting the error `TypeError: "a is undefined"`in the console. I am still learning Javascript and I can't see where I am going wrong. (I have included the keyboard logic and the character movement this time for clarity.)

```
function MyBackground(game, x, y) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'background');

}

MyBackground.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
MyBackground.prototype.constructor = MyScene;

MyBackground.prototype.repeatScene = function () {
    this.nextFrame = new Phaser.Sprite(this.game, this.width, 0, "background", 0);
    this.game.add.existing(this.nextFrame);
};



function Hero(game, x, y) {
        Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'player');

this.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
    this.game.physics.enable(this);
    this.body.collideWorldBounds = false;


    this.animations.add('stop', [0]);
    this.animations.add('run', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 14, true); // 14fps looped
    this.animations.add('jump', [6]);
    this.animations.add('fall', [7]);
    this.animations.add('die', [8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9], 12); // 12fps no loop

}

Hero.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Hero.prototype.constructor = Hero;

Hero.prototype.move = function (direction) {
  const SPEED = 200;
    this.body.velocity.x = direction * SPEED;


    // update image flipping & animations
    if (this.body.velocity.x < 0) {
        this.scale.x = -1;
    }
    else if (this.body.velocity.x > 0) {
        this.scale.x = 1;
    }
};

Hero.prototype.jump = function () {
    const JUMP_SPEED = 600;
    let canJump = this.body.touching.down;


    if (canJump) {
    this.body.velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
  }
  return canJump;
};

Hero.prototype.bounce = function () {
   const BOUNCE_SPEED = 200;
   this.body.velocity.y = -BOUNCE_SPEED;
};

Hero.prototype.update = function () {
    // update sprite animation, if it needs changing
    let animationName = this._getAnimationName();
    if (this.animations.name !== animationName) {
        this.animations.play(animationName);
    }

};

Hero.prototype.die = function () {
    this.alive = false;
    this.body.enable = false;

    this.animations.play('die').onComplete.addOnce(function () {
        this.kill();
    }, this);
};


Hero.prototype._getAnimationName = function () {
    let name = 'stop'; // default animation

    if (!this.alive) {
        name = 'die';
    }

    else if (this.body.velocity.y > 0 && !this.body.touching.down) { 
        name = 'fall';
    }

    else if (this.body.velocity.y < 0) {
        name = 'jump';
    }

    else if (this.body.velocity.x !== 0 && this.body.touching.down ) {
        name = 'run';
    }

    return name;

PlayState = {};

PlayState.init = function () {
    this.game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;

    this.keys = this.game.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        left: Phaser.KeyCode.LEFT,
        right: Phaser.KeyCode.RIGHT,
        up: Phaser.KeyCode.UP
};

PlayState.preload = function () {

      this.game.load.json('level:1', 'data/level01.json');

      this.game.load.image('ground', 'images/ground.png'); // I need this to repeat infinitely

      this.game.load.image('background', 'images/background.png'); // I need this to repeat infinitely

      this.game.load.spritesheet('player', 'images/player.png', 64, 64);

};


PlayState.create = function () {

  this.background = new MyBackground(this.game, 0, 0);
  this.game.add.existing(this.MyBackground);


  this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.game.ground);
  this.game.ground.body.immovable = true; 
  this.game.ground.body.allowGravity = false; 

  this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

  this._loadLevel(this.game.cache.getJSON('level:1'));
  this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, this.MyBackground.width * 2, 800);

};


PlayState.update = function () {

   var backgroundWidth = this.game.stage.getChildAt(0).getBounds().width; //getChildAt(0) because the background is created first in create


   if (this.x > backgroundWidth * .75) {

      this.x = backgroundWidth * .25;

      repeatScene();  

     };

  this._handleInput();
  this.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.game.ground); 

 };


    PlayState._handleInput = function () {


                if (this.keys.up.isDown) {
                    this.player.jump();

                } else  if (this.keys.right.isDown) { // move hero right
                    this.player.move(1);

                  } else if (this.keys.left.isDown) { // move hero left
                    this.player.move(-1);
                } else { // stop
                    this.player.move(0);
                }
      };


PlayState._loadLevel = function (data) {

       this._spawnPlayer({player: data.player});
       const GRAVITY = 1200;
       this.game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = GRAVITY;
      };

PlayState._spawnPlayer = function (data) {

       this.player = new Hero(this.game, data.player.x, data.player.y);
       this.game.add.existing(this.player);
       this.game.camera.follow(this.player, Phaser.Camera.FOLLOW_PLATFORMER);
      };

window.onload = function () {
        let game = new Phaser.Game(866, 520, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');
        game.state.add('play', PlayState);
        game.state.start('play');
};
```

Comment: Infinite loop is meant to be "Infinite", right? If you need the logic to be stop on some condition, Infinite loop may not suit you. Where is the logic to control the character movement? Maybe there should be the place to move the background?

Comment: Mr. Brickowski thanks for your suggestion, there is a solution for this that does not involve the logic controlling the character. I have edited my question to expand on this.

Comment: I don't see an `a` variable called or used. But if I read your question correctly, it sounds like you converted TypeScript over to JS instead of providing the original TS. Perhaps including the TS might help?